# Why does JavaScript output 16384 instead of 040000?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have encountered a very weird issue with my JavaScript program. I have fount that JavaScript for some reason changes `040000` into `16384`! [[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/codeapprentice/t26H3/)] Does anyone know why JavaScript is doing this?

Comment: If you really need to have a number pre-padded with zeros, try using strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because javascript thinks its in `OCTAL` format

**Explanation**:-

`Javascript` (like most programming languages) allows us to work directly with both `octal` and `hexadecimal` numbers, all we need is a way to tell which number base we are using when we specify a number. To identify `octal` and `hexadecimal` numbers we add something to the front of numbers using those bases to indicate which base we are using. A leading `0` on the front of a number indicates that the number following is octal while a leading `0x` indicates a hexadecimal number. The decimal number `18` can therefore also be represented as `022` (in `octal`) and `0x12` (in `hexadecimal`). We don't put a special symbol on the front of decimal numbers so any number that doesn't start with `0` or `0x` is assumed to be decimal.

So its same in your case

```
040000(base8)=16384(base10)
```

Answer (score 7):

It's because in js, number literals prepended with `0` are considered **octal** (base 8)

For example

```
010 == 8
```

In your example `040000` is really `4*8*8*8*8 = 16384` because in octal each `0` in the right multiplies the value by 8.

**EDIT: Bonus**:

If the leading 0 is in a string representation, (for example, if it was introduced by the user), and you want to avoid converting to octal, specify the base (aka *radix*) with value `10` in the `parseInt` method call, like this

```
var number = parseInt("040000", 10);  //number will be 40000 ;)
```

In recent browsers, the radix is 10 by default, *but not in old browsers*, so if you want maximum compatibility also, *always specify the radix parameter* (usually 10).

Cheers

Comment: Why octal? Wouldn't `base4` or `base2 (binary)` be more realistic? Is there any way I can avoid this?

Comment: @Progo: why do you have a leading `0` in the first place? Is it from user input, or from server-side variables?

Comment: If your value is originally a string, you can use `parseInt('040000', 10)`. If it is 040000 as an integer, it is not 40000, it is 16384. The leading zero is just octal notation.

Comment: @Scopey, I added just that at the same time as your comment xD. That's right :)

Comment: @Progo, see the solution to that problem in my edition

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado - `parseInt('040000', 10)` will return 40000 not 16384! (Atleast for me in the latest version of Chrome. - You made me check)

Comment: @Scopey omg, of course scopey, that's obvious. editing, My bad, sorry xD