# Javascript Leading 0 on Integers Wrong Value

Tags: javascript

Javascript leading 0 on integers getting wrong value on `console.log`. 
Why I am getting like this ?

Code:

```
console.log(456);
console.log(0456);
```

Output:

```
456
302
```

Comment: leading `0` tells JS engine that it  is an octal number.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/21036122/8813684

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because JS "translates" 0456 as an octal value, since it has a trailing zero and all its digits < 8.

Comment: octal for 0456 is 710 ? http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-octal-converter

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr It's obvious that you should do an octal to decimal conversion, not the opposite.